# what does 'by; in pseudocode mean

Tags: loops, pseudocode

I am trying to understand a Wikipedia pseudocode but i can't understand what is meant by:

```
for k = 0 to n-1 by m
```

What does "by m" mean in here? 
code is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#Data_reordering,_bit_reversal,_and_in-place_algorithms).

Comment: It's the step value, you go from `0` to `n-1` by adding `m`, so you go over the values `0`, `m`, `2*m`, `3*m`, ... until you reach `n-1`.

Comment: @Dominique: please make that an answer instead of a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the step value, you go from `0` to `n-1` by adding `m`, so you go over the values `0`, `m`, `2*m`, `3*m`, ... until you reach `n-1`.